# return values within the last 365 counting from newest date ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, count

[ORACLE SQL] I'm trying to write a query that returns all the values in a single column in the last 365 days counting from the last time (or newest date; in other words) data was entered.

For example: table: EMPLOYEE_TIMESTAMPS

### EMPLOYEE_ID    TIMESTAMP_DATE

```
1              AUG 2014
1              AUG 2015
2              JAN 2016
1              FEB 2016
1              OCT 2016
```

the resulting data should be only the last two rows, as it should count 365 days from OCT 2016 backwards.

I tried using the following code but resulted in [ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here] because of the MAX function. Using SYSDATE does not get the job done as the last data could have been added months ago.

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE_TIMESTAMPS
WHERE TIMESTAMP_DATE >= MAX(TIMESTAMP_DATE) -365;
```

I'm fairly new to programming so I still have a hard time transmitting my ideas. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `..WHERE TIMESTAMP_DATE >=(select MAX(TIMESTAMP_DATE) -365 from EMPLOYEE_TIMESTAMPS);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method of doing what you want uses window functions:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT et.*,
             MAX(TIMESTAMP_DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE_ID) as MAX_TIMESTAMP_DATE
      FROM EMPLOYEE_TIMESTAMPS
     ) et
WHERE TIMESTAMP_DATE >= MAX_TIMESTAMP_DATE - 365;
```

The problem with your version is the use of the aggregation function `MAX()`.  First, there is no `GROUP BY` in the query.  And, second, these functions are not allowed in the `WHERE` clause.

The `MAX()` in the above version is called an analytic function, because it has the `OVER` clause.